# Together we are? (It's not what you see that counts)

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Try make sense of this little puzzle below. The full answer is twelve letters long but it's usually abbreviated.

---

The numbers below are arranged in order

---

```
237       238 
358       689
995       233
972       225
1876      441534
971       1
44        598
```

---

Hint1

> Mostly three digit numbers... Why is that?

Comment: I have to assume the 12 letter answer isn't simply the thing used in the first step? That's also 12 letters but doesn't seem puzzling enough.

Comment: @Amoz No, that's completely coincidental and not the answer i'm looking for. Try to see a pattern..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is:

> **[GROUP OF SEVEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Seven)**, usually abbreviated to **G7**, i.e. the international political forum comprised of Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, the UK, and the USA.

To find this, note first that the listed numbers are all:

> valid **international dialling codes** (i.e. the prefixes you use before the local phone number when calling somebody in another country).

And these relate to:

> 237 CAMEROON
>  238 CAPE VERDE
>
>  358 FINLAND
>  689 FRENCH POLYNESIA
>
>  995 GEORGIA
>  233 GHANA
>
>  972 ISRAEL
>  225 IVORY COAST
>
>  1876 JAMAICA
>  441534 JERSEY
>
>  971 UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
>  1 UNITED STATES
>
>  44 UNITED KINGDOM
>  598 URUGUAY

Note next that these pairs:

> indicate countries which are very close together alphabetically. Armed with the title hint that it's 'not what you see that counts' let's look at the nations that come *in between* these countries in a list of international dialling codes.

What you draw out of this process really depends on what you consider as your authoritative information source here, but I can identify the following 'inbetweeners':

> CANADA
>  FRANCE, FRENCH ANTILLES, FRENCH GUIANA
>  GERMANY
>  ITALY
>  JAPAN
>  UK
>  UNITED STATES, UNITED STATES VIRGIN ISLANDS

And by now the intended pattern is clear:

> If we take only the most major of all the countries listed above, then we produce the group: CANADA, FRANCE, GERMANY, ITALY, JAPAN, UK, and USA. These are clearly recognisable as the group of nations that make up the **Group of Seven** (I wonder how they came up with that name?!), which should surely be the 12-letter answer intended here!

Comment: This is the correct answer, well done!